# Res.Render Is Stalling

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Sorry if I'm sharing too much (or too little!) I'm not sure how to provide code when it's contained in multiple files like this.

In the small project I have my app.js server using express and ejs. I have a "/compose" route which creates a blog post with a "Title" and "Content". It then pushes this into a global array called "posts".

In the "/posts" route, my intention is that the server is supposed to loop over the "posts" array containing the posts and match the correct post title with the "postName" parameter given in the URL. (I am trying to make the Titles case insensitive with the .toLowerCase() method on the strings.)

However, when I do this, the page just stalls and doesn't actually load. A curious bug though is that if I "reload" the server (I'm running nodemon) by even making a small change to the app.js code such as changing a comma or commenting out a line, such that nodemon reloads, the page will display the requested information.

```js
// This is my app.js code
const express = require("express");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

const posts = [];

app.get("/posts/:postName", (req, res) => {
  const requestedTitle = req.params.postName.toLowerCase();
  posts.forEach(post => {
    const storedTitle = post.title.toLowerCase();
    if (requestedTitle === storedTitle) {
      res.render("post", {
        post: post
      });
    }
  });
});

app.post("/compose", (req, res) => {
  const post = {
    title: req.body.postTitle,
    content: req.body.postBody
  };
  posts.push(post);
  res.redirect("/")
})
```

```html
<!-- This is my "Post" route HTML code (a partial called post.ejs) -->
<h1>This is
  <%= post.title%>
</h1>

<!-- This is my "Compose" route HTML Code (a partial called compose.ejs) -->
<h1>Compose</h1>
<form action="/compose" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="postTitle">Title</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="postTitle" autofocus>
    <label for="postBody">Post</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="postBody" id="" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button">Publish</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I see is that your `app.get("/posts/:postName", ...)` route needs to always send one and only one http response.  The way it is coded now, it will send no response if a matching post isn't found and it will attempt to send multiple responses if more than one is found.  Both conditions are a problem.

Here's one way to fix that:

```
app.get("/posts/:postName", (req, res) => {
    const requestedTitle = req.params.postName.toLowerCase();
    for (let post of posts) {
        const storedTitle = post.title.toLowerCase();
        if (requestedTitle === storedTitle) {
            res.render("post", {
                post: post
            });
            return;
        }
    }
    // send some sort of response here with a 404 status
    res.sendStatus(404);
});
```

As a possible explanation for the server behavior you saw, the browser will only send so many requests in-flight at the same time to the same host.  So, if with your original code, you are playing with URLs that don't have matching posts, those will not get responses sent back to the browser from the server and those requests will still be waiting for a response.  Eventually the browser will hit the max requests that it will send to your host until some of them finish.  Thus, it will appear that your server becomes non-responsive to new requests, when in reality it's just waiting for prior requests to finish.  You must always send one and only one response from your server to each incoming http request.

---

I assume this posts array is probably just a temporary storage mechanism, but it would be a lot more efficient if you replaced the array with a Map object with the lowercase title as the key.  Then, you could just directly lookup the matching title on the Map object with one `map.get()` operation rather than looping through the whole array.

Comment: Thank you! I'm at work right now but I will rewrite this to make sure and send at least 1 response and return to report!

Comment: So I used the code you put up. The page is rendering and no longer stalling but now in the console I am getting this error: 
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client.

However, when I put the res.sendStatus(404) inside of an "else" statement, it went away. This is so weird. I'm doing a bootcamp and following along exactly with their code but this has for some reason caused so many problems that I couldn't find anyone else experiencing.

Any idea why putting it into an "else" statement made it go away?

Comment: Also, the code seems to not work if there is more than 1 post object (structured like {post: "title", content: "This is the content") in the posts array. It will only get the first post item in the array. (I'm sure there are better ways to go over the "posts" as with the map method you outlined earlier but this is just the code/solution the teacher had). 

I'm just not sure why it's causing me so much trouble and I've had to alter it so much when the original code I posted was basically the solution and it worked for others. I just want to understand!

Comment: @ai88 - Which code has that problem of only matching the first item in the `posts` array?  Your code or my code?

Comment: `ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT` is caused by your code trying to send more than one response to the same request.  Your code in your question can do that.  The code in my answer will not. I'm not sure what code you're running that is still generating that error.  Keep in mind that `res.send(...)` does not stop your code from executing - it keeps on going and if it decides to call `res.send(...)` again, you will get this error.

Comment: Thank you so much again for your help again. I can't thank you enough. Here is the code I'm running which isn't working:

```app.get("/posts/:postName", (req, res) => {
  const requestedTitle = req.params.postName.toLowerCase();
  posts.forEach(post => {
    const storedTitle = post.title.toLowerCase();
    if (requestedTitle === storedTitle) {
      console.log("Found a match")
      res.render("post", {
        post: post
      });
      return;
    }
  });
  // sending some sort of response here with a 404 status
 res.sendStatus(404) 
});```

Comment: I'm so sorry that's not formatting right even when I used the ``` ```. Is there another way to format code in the comments with the right indentation like I did in my original question?

The code you graciously provided runs correctly but mine doesn't.  For the life of me I can't figure out why. The only difference I can see is I'm using a forEach method on the array whereas you used a traditional 'for' loop. Is there a fundamental, structural difference? The two problems are: a) it can't seem to render anything but the first post in the array and b) it always sends that error.

Comment: @ai88 - Multiline code in comments never works.  I can read enough of it to see that you're still using `.forEach()` and thus when you find a match, you don't stop the loop because `.forEach()` doesn't support stopping the loop.  PLEASE see the code in my answer.  It will not have this problem.  Use a `for` loop instead like my answer shows.  Then, you can `return` or `break` to stop the loop when you find a match.

Comment: Thank you so much again. I cannot tell you how much I appreciate your time and response. Best to you and yours.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming here with this issue from Dr Angela's tutorial/course, I had this issue and solved it by removing the `<script src="lodash.js"></script>` from my 'header.ejs' file.

If you've already used `npm install lodash` in the terminal for your project, you don't need both as it seems to cause a severe slowdown rendering the page.

Once removed the pages loaded instantly.